# 401 Unauthorized error for GET request in Ionic 2?

Tags: web-services, http, angular, ionic2

I have below get request. But its giving `401 Unauthorized` error.

```
var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');

        this.http.get(urgentPostURL + encodeURIComponent(this.urgentpost.comment))
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => { 

          this.result = data;
          console.log('UrgentPost Result : ' + this.result.Success);

          if (this.result.Success == true) {
              console.log("SUCESSS");
          } else {
              console.log("FAILED");
          }

        },err => console.error(err),() => console.log('done'));
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

### Edited

After updated to the following code I'm still getting 401:

```
var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa("123" + ':' + "123"));
        this.http.get(urgentPostURL + encodeURIComponent(this.urgentpost.comment), { headers: headers })
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
```

General:

```
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
```

Response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:0
Date:Tue, 23 Feb 2016 11:26:17 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Set-Cookie:ARRAffinity=6e6dd0608a0902ef40a800ab07ee37397d7b6cfbd85cf3dea254a7115d365bc1;Path=/;Domain=sd.sddd.net
WWW-Authenticate:Basic
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Request headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic MDAwMDAwMDoxMjM0NTY3OA==
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host:sd.sddd.net
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seems that the server requires authentication. You didn't define the `Authorization` header for your call.

Here is a sample for an HTTP basic authentication:

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
headers.append('Authorizcation', 'Basic '+btoa(username + ':' + password));

this.http.get(urgentPostURL + encodeURIComponent(
          this.urgentpost.comment,
          { headers: headers })
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    (...)
```

Don't forget to specify your headers for your request and to import the `Headers` class.

Comment: Thank you Thierry. I've got successful status (200k) but it throws this error. "XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'my_url'. Request header field Authorizcation is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response". and these are my imports: import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Http, Headers } from 'angular2/http';

Comment: Great! What do you have in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`? Does the response of the preflighted request (the OPTIONS request) contain `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916623/angular2-http-request-not-able-to-add-headers/34917039#34917039

Comment: Yes, response has Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true.

Comment: This is a part of my response: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:0

Comment: I see this in your error message `"field Authorizcation is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers"`. `Authorizcation` should be `Authorization`...

Comment: I updated my question. It again gives 401. I cannot think of what I'm missing here.

Comment: Are you sure that you server uses HTTP basic auth? Do the provided credentials allow you to authenticated on the server side? I mean: is it a valid username / password?

Comment: Yes, actually below is the code snippet I need to convert. $http.get(serviceURL + 'Urgent?messageContent=' + encodeURIComponent($scope.messageContent)).
                  success(function (data, status, headers, config) {.. Earlier I have used this code and worked fine.

Comment: I would leverage the `URLSearchParams` class for query parameters: URLSearchParams search = new URLSearchParams();
search.set('messageContent', messageContent);
this.http.get(serviceURL + 'Urgent', { headers: headers, search: search })

Comment: var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa("123" + ':' + "123"));
        URLSearchParams search = new URLSearchParams(); 
        search.set('messageContent', this.urgentpost.comment); 
        this.http.get(SERVER_URL + 'Urgent', 
         { headers: headers, search: search }).. but No luck Thierry. Same error. Thank you very much for your time. Let me try this little bit and I will comment the status tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Thierry, finally I solved it out. Thanks alot. I marked your answer as correct. I needed to add appname for authorization headers. You helped me alot in this :) Thank you.

Comment: Without setting it always cannot I do this in Angular 2.document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");
                            var encoded = Base64.encode($scope.username + ':' + $scope.password + ':' + appName); 
                            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + encoded;

Comment: You're welcome! I think this question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375530/how-do-i-add-a-json-web-token-to-each-header/35377964#35377964.